# Python - navigate through and show images in a folder

Tags: python-3.x, loops, opencv

I'm trying to write a script to show the images in a folder, and navigate through them according to the key pressed by the user.

So, say that the program opens and displays the first image. If the user presses:

```
key1 -> show previous image  
key2 -> show next image  
key3 -> copy image somewhere else  
key4 -> exit program
```

So far, I have:

```
import os
import cv2



def main():
    input_images_path = "something"
    output_images_path = "something"

    images_list = [image_name for image_name in os.listdir(input_images_path)]

    print("Press 'x' for previous image, 'v' for next one, 'c' to copy image and corresponding label." )

    step = 0
    while(True):
        img = cv2.imread(input_images_path+images_list[step], 1)
        cv2.imshow(f'current image', img)

        if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('c'):
            print("\tCopying this one")
        elif cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('x'):
            step = step-1
        elif cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('v'):
            step +=1
        elif cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It kinda works, but it usually requires me to press the key multiple times to make something happen (previous/next image or copy). I guess it has something to do with the various waitKey...how can I fix it?

Also, how can I use the left and right arrow to navigate through images?

Comment: Well, read your code. Right now it goes like "Wait for a keypress. If it wasn't `c`, wait for another keypress. If that one wasn't `x`, wait for yet another keypress. If the third one wasn't a `v`, wait for fourth one..." | Use a variable and only call `waitKey` once per iteration.

Comment: Yes, I got confused on how waitKey() works. I fixed it in the meanwhile, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, fixed it:

```
    index = 0
    while(True):
        img = cv2.imread(input_images_path+images_list[index], 1)
        cv2.imshow(f'current image', img)
        key = cv2.waitKey(0)

        if key == ord('c'):
            print("\tCopying this one")
        elif key == ord('x'):
            index -= 1
        elif key == ord('v'):
            index +=1
        elif key == ord('q'):
            break

        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Still have to figure how to use the arrow keys to navigate, I'll look to that now.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! Really helped to make a simple image classifier for dividing dataset images!